# iPhone code leaks and I don't know why

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks

this is a well known snippet, how to select a picture from the iPhone photo library:

```
- (IBAction)selectExistingPicture {
  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
            [picker release];

  }
}
```

Here you can see a screenshot of Instruments ([fullscreen](http://img.skitch.com/20090624-rtqp2mgsnyynkgb97c9e8d2g9c.jpg)).

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20090624-rtqp2mgsnyynkgb97c9e8d2g9c.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090624-rtqp2mgsnyynkgb97c9e8d2g9c.jpg)

Why does it leak? I don't understand it, because picker is released properly, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `UIImagePickerController` is [known to leak](http://blog.airsource.co.uk/index.php/2008/11/12/memory-usage-in-uiimagepickercontroller/). If you are going to use it more than once it's recommended that you reuse a single instance

Comment: Ok, thank you. Strange that Apple rejects apps due to leaks, but produces leaks themselves.

Answer (score 4):

You are presenting picker but then losing the pointer to it when you leave the method. As it is allocated memory, that is your leak. Try:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: I tried this before: same issue. Sorry, I forgot: [picker release] in my post. Edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be doing an autorelease on the UIImagePickerController?

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: Same answer as above ;-) I tried this before: same issue. Sorry, I forgot: [picker release] in my post. Edited it.